# How to show particular div based upon id, id will be dyanamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am having list of div with ids, it will generate based upon the number of pages [image]

Now I have to show pageContainer1 and pageContainer6  it may differ.

```
  $scope.comment_pg_filter = function(){
        $scope.page_id=[];
       $http.post('/getcommentlist',{file_id : $scope.file_id}).then(function(response){
                     console.log(response)
                     if(response.data != null){
                         $scope.comments = response.data;
                        //  $scope.comments_length = $scope.comments.length;
                         console.log($scope.comments)
                         angular.forEach($scope.comments,function(comments_pg){
                             console.log(comments_pg.pageNumber);
                             $scope.page_id.push("#pageContainer"+comments_pg.pageNumber)

                         })
                      console.log($scope.page_id) // Here am getting ['pageContainer1','pageContainer6']
                     }
       })

    }
```

Now I have to show these two div alone and I have to Hide all other .. How to do that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ng-show`. You can update your template to following.

```
<div id="pageContainer1" data-ng-show="page_id.indexOf('pageContainer1') !== -1">...</div>
<div id="pageContainer2" data-ng-show="page_id.indexOf('pageContainer2') !== -1">...</div>
<div id="pageContainer6" data-ng-show="page_id.indexOf('pageContainer6') !== -1">...</div>
```

**EDIT**

Without editing html, using Javascript

```js
let ids = ["container1", "container4"];
document.querySelectorAll(".page").forEach(el => el.style.display = ids.includes(el.id) ? 'display' : 'none');
```

```html
<div class="page" id="container1">Container 1</div>
<div class="page" id="container2">Container 2</div>
<div class="page" id="container3">Container 3</div>
<div class="page" id="container4">Container 4</div>
<div class="page" id="container5">Container 5</div>
```

Comment: But the pages are generated from pdf.js

Comment: So if you can not update the html, then you will have to use javascript / jquery to achieve what you want. Are you okay using that?

Comment: inside ng-click function can I able to use that means no problem

Comment: I have updated my answer where I show all the div with class `page` with ids that match the values in array and hide rest all.

Comment: every pages are getting hide

Comment: There is `ids.includes` in the above code. In your code it will be `page_id.includes`. Also, you will need to push only `id's` and not `#id` in array.

Comment: Thank you so much Its working..Actually I have included # in my array so only it doesn't work

Comment: Glad to help you :)